# ANDROID: Error W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to do a MapActivity using Android Studio. It has to show the user’s location.

Well, I know I need a key in order to use the API, and believe me, I changed that key at least four times… I also have the permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml.

The thing is I can show the map without the user’s location, but if I try to show his/her location, then the app compiles well BUT when I try to execute it, it stops and I obtain this error:

```
11-12 09:13:28.416 21576-21653/raquel.mapapplication W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
11-12 09:13:28.424 21576-21653/raquel.mapapplication I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:2
11-12 09:13:28.424 21576-21653/raquel.mapapplication I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 2
11-12 09:13:28.432 21576-21653/raquel.mapapplication W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000b/n/armeabi
11-12 09:13:28.436 21576-21653/raquel.mapapplication D/GoogleCertificates: com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates module is loaded
11-12 09:13:28.504 21576-21653/raquel.mapapplication D/GoogleCertificatesImpl: Fetched 190 Google release certificates
11-12 09:13:28.505 21576-21653/raquel.mapapplication D/GoogleCertificatesImpl: Fetched 363 Google certificates
11-12 09:13:31.235 21576-21576/raquel.mapapplication I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21576 SIG: 9
```

It mentions something about Google Certificates, and that is why I thought maybe it has something to do with the key… But I am not sure and I do not have idea what I am doing wrong.

Thank you for your help.

////////

Ok, I will try to post some code... I have been changing the code all the time, but this is the last I tried (I also tried setMyLocationEnable(true), because getMyLocation() is deprecated, but I obtain the same error):

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        Location location=mMap.getMyLocation();

        double lat=location.getLatitude();
        double lon=location.getLongitude();

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(lat, lon);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Thanks the person who answered me and the person who edited my comment... I still do not well how to format text...

Comment: Can you include a bit of code as well please?

Comment: Try to update the SHA1 key in your project on Google Developer Console and update the Google Maps API key in your android project. For better understanding, make sure you follow properly the steps given in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#if-you-are-using-the-standard-google-maps-android-api) especially the part of ["Where to get your app's SHA-1 fingerprint"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#fingerprint)

Comment: Hi Raquel, did you fix it? (I have same problem here)

Comment: i am facing same issue...please let me know if you found any solution. @Raquel

Answer (score 6):

Open the `sdk manager`, download/update `google play services`.
And create a new emulator.

Comment: Update: Downloading updated Google Play Services for the selected API version -> deleting and reinstalling emulator for that API -> restarting Android Studio did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Loading certificates may be the bug in API and i think somewhere any google developer also have described it that play service is trying to do sign in to verify play app or third party app so that could be error. I do not know more further about it.

but if you are still having trouble with placing marker on user,s position you can try below code i have tested it and is working in application

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)

{
    myGoogleMap = googleMap;
    placeMarkerOnPosition();
}

public void placeMarkerOnPosition() {
//// check permissions to access resources ///////// 
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && 
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    return;
}
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Now you can find it with two ways

```
////////////////  find location if GPS provider is available (GPS should 
enable to envoke this callback)

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, 
new LocationListener() 
{
 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

try {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());                              
    myLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    myLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng myPosition = new LatLng(myLatitude,myLongitude);
    List<Address> places=geocoder.getFromLocation(myLatitude, 
    myLongitude,1);
    myLocation = places.get(0).getSubLocality() 
                 +""+places.get(0).getLocality();

    myGoogleMap.clear();
    myGoogleMap.addMarker(new 
    MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title(myLocation));

    myGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPosition, 
                                                                 13.5f));


    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
    });

////////////////   checking with network providers   /////////


if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {


locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 
                                       0, new LocationListener() {
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
myLatitude = location.getLatitude();
myLongitude = location.getLongitude();
LatLng myPosition = new LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude);
myGoogleMap.clear();
myGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("My 
                                                             Position"));

myGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPosition, 
                                                              13.5f));
```

}

```
                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) 
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                }
            });

        }

   ////////  Or you can find it with user  recent location //////////

   Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
   String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true);
   Locationlocation=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

   //////////   load your location from last recent locations ////////
            if (location != null) {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());

                try {
                    myLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                    myLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                    LatLng myPosition = new LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude);
                    List<Address> places = 
                    geocoder.getFromLocation(myLatitude, myLongitude, 1);
                    myLocation = places.get(0).getSubLocality() + " " + places.get(0).getLocality();

                    myGoogleMap.clear();
                    myGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title(myLocation));
                    myGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPosition, 13.5f));


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Hint: you have a lot of code there - very lazily formatted/indented. Please use that **preview** window to ensure that you don't dump some code mess, but something that people will find readable enough.